# Why not use only boolean

Tags: vhdl

What are the reasons for using `std_logic` or `std_ulogic` instead of `boolean`?

`std_logic` can have other values than `'1'` and `'0'`, but in an FPGA everything is resolved to either `'1'` or `'0'`. Doesn't this make simulations more unrealistic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `std_logic` type can take on the following values:

```
• 'U': uninitialized. This signal hasn't been set yet. 
• 'X': unknown. Impossible to determine this value/result. 
• '0': logic 0 
• '1': logic 1 
• 'Z': High Impedance 
• 'W': Weak signal, can't tell if it should be 0 or 1. 
• 'L': Weak signal that should probably go to 0 
• 'H': Weak signal that should probably go to 1 
• '-': Don't care.
```

So far more than the `bool` that will not tell you that the signal was too weak or what it "probably" should be. So to answer your question the reason is that when using signal inputs you are hoping to get more information than just '0' or '1' should something not go according to design.

[Reference to the std_logic_1164](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~ggbaker/reference/std_logic/1164/index.html)

Comment: Good answer.  Can you provide a URL that points to this information?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out what I forgot. I added a reference to the library defenitions for std_logic_1164.

Comment: Note also that `std_logic` makes simulations *more* realistic, not less. Real-world circuits can have tri-state drivers (`'Z'`), pull-ups (`'H'`), etc. `boolean` (and `bit` for that matter) don't allow you to model these things.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do a really good job, you would only use std_logic on your FPGA pins.  You're right that once the signals in the FPGA, they are all resolved into either 0's or 1's.  I have seen it done on some FPGA designs.  Only the top level entity has `std_logic` type.  Every other lower level component uses `bit` and `bit_vector` types.  It makes your code as realistic as possible.  However it does cause some headaches when trying to use anyone else's modules, because very few people do not use `std_logic` for their interfaces.

As another person already said, `std_logic` can be resolved into 'X', 'H', 'Z', etc, but these are only ever seen on FPGA interfaces.